# Update pickerView with data asynchronously

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I would like to update a pickerView at the start of my application or asynchronously after my view is loaded
I request the data that goes inside asynchronously to WebService and I have no idea how to do this.

I tried to :

- Override the loadView() method to get the JSON array while the view is loading so I can put it in my pickerView
- Call the pickerView's delegate methods in a Dispatch.main.async { //Code }

Here is the data

```
[
  {"idPoint":6,"ptName":"Maison","ptLat":43.72623997050257,"ptLong":2.202591651830584},
  {"idPoint":7,"ptName":"Wheelin","ptLat":42.75754326128173,"ptLong":8.137330631668685},
  {"idPoint":8,"ptName":"Animoz","ptLat":45.76321863196126,"ptLong":7.137186047202841},
  {"idPoint":9,"ptName":"Hesias","ptLat":45.767222865412144,"ptLong":6.132352002277385},
  {"idPoint":10,"ptName":"Marcombes","ptLat":45.76018235160473,"ptLong":4.085466264251463},
  {"idPoint":11,"ptName":"Leclan","ptLat":48.80950120948317,"ptLong":2.110623123039061},
  {"idPoint":12,"ptName":"Cournon Skatepark","ptLat":39.74138613175866,"ptLong":4.2154977334348906}
]
```

My data fetcher

```swift
struct PointFetcher {

    static func fetchPoint(completion: @escaping ([Point]) -> ()) {
        struct tempPoint: Decodable {
            let idPoint:Int
            let ptName:String
            let ptLat:Double
            let ptLong:Double
        }

        guard let url = URL(string: "MyWebService.com") else {
            completion([])
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                completion([])
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                completion([])
                return
            }

            do {
                let points = try JSONDecoder().decode([tempPoint].self, from: data)
                var returnArray: [Point] = []
                for pts in points {
                    let pTemp = Point(name: pts.ptName, coord: CLLocation(latitude: pts.ptLat, longitude: pts.ptLong))
                    returnArray.append(pTemp)
                }
                print(returnArray)
                completion(returnArray)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

The Viewcontroller.swift is empty just the viewDidLoad() inside, the IBOutlet of the view picker and its delegates (numberOfComponent, numberOfRowsInComponent, titleForRow, didSelectRow

Thanks !

Comment: After you update the array you can use `reloadComponent`

Comment: all you have to do is set the new data to the pickerView. You can do it inside viewDidLoad